# How to store multiple string as a single array in String.xml file

Tags: android, string

I am learning Andoid Development using Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide book. In chapter 2, book develops an Quiz app, where it stores questions in `string.xml` file as follows:

```
<string name="question_mideast">The Suez Canal connects the Red Sea
and the Indian Ocean?</string>
```

The problem with this approach is when I have a lot of strings I (say 1000), I can't call each string by name. A better way is maybe storing strings in an array. So that I can call a particular string as string[2][23] (i.e, string of chapter 2, text number 23).

1. Could you tell me how to save strings in String.xml files as array?
2. Is there any better way to deal when you have lots of strings, in terms of performance.

Comment: put on `.txt` and read from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it in `arrays.xml` instead. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/samples/MediaRouter/res/values/arrays.html) example file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <string-array name="your_string">
    <item>A</item>
    <item>B</item>
    <item>C</item>
    <item>D</item>
 </string-array> 
</resources>
```

Read it in Java Code as.

```
String[] mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_string);
```

Comment: Hello Abdul, it says "can't resolve getResources()". Can you help?

Comment: Call it from a `Context` like an `Activity`. Where are you calling it from?

Answer (score 1):

User String-array

```
<string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: This example is copied from the documentation. You should at least mention that.

Comment: @rekire Please give me link i have got it from navigation drawer example

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Comment: @rekire and i don't think that i have to give Navigation drawer link for String array

Comment: @rekire please download sample from this link https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html and open String.xml have string array

Comment: I know how that works. I also added a reference to the IMHO *original* source, that example there is 6 or 7 years old.